# Implementing sortInPlace with closure as MutableCollectionType extension

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I'm trying to add two methods to `Card` arrays, such that I could call `cardArray.suitSort()` or `cardArray.rankSort()` to perform a `sortInPlace({})` with the appropriate comparison function between the brackets.  However, when compiling the below code, I get the error "Ambiguous reference to member sortInPlace" that stick whether I leave the `self.` part in or not.

```
extension MutableCollectionType where Generator.Element == Card {
    mutating func suitSort() {
        self.sortInPlace({SuitSorted($0,$1)})
    }
    mutating func rankSort() {
        self.sortInPlace({RankSorted($0,$1)})
    }
}
```

How can I get this to work, so I don't have to use `sortInPlace({comparisonFunction($0,$1)})` every time I want to sort an `Array<Card>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this dilemma by using a Protocol called CardCollection and code that's somewhat similar to the following:

```
protocol CardCollection : RangeReplaceableCollectionType, CustomStringConvertible {
    var collective : [Card] { get set }
}

extension CardCollection  {
    mutating func shuffleInPlace() {
        collective.shuffleInPlace()
    }

    // This is where the generic sorter takes place
    mutating func sortInPlace(sortFun: (Card, Card) -> Bool?=DisplaySorted) {
        collective.sortInPlace({sortFun($0,$1)!})
    }

    mutating func sortBySuit() {
        sortInPlace(SuitSorted)
    }
    mutating func sortByRank() {
        sortInPlace(RankSorted)
    }
    mutating func sortForDisplay() {
        sortInPlace(DisplaySorted)
    }
}
```